# How many curves in a family possess a rational point?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider $B$ a finite-type integral quasi-projective scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $B(\mathbb{Z})$ infinite. (If you like, take $B$ to be the affine line). Let $X \to B$ be a generically smooth proper family of curves of genus $g > 1$. Assume the $b \in B(\mathbb{Z})$ for which $X_b(\mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$ are Zariski-dense in $B$. 
Must then the proportion of members $X_b$, over $b \in B(\mathbb{Z})$, for which $X_b(\mathbb{Q}) \neq \emptyset$, be equal to $0$? (Variant: the same question with $B(\mathbb{Z})$ replaced by $B(\mathbb{Q})$.)

*An explicit variant (although not quite a special case as it stands)*. Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be irreducible of degree $> 4$. Do the integers $N$ for which $f(x) = Ny^2$ has a rational solution, have density zero? Variant: let $N$ range over the primes, or over the squarefrees.

In the above setup, we may include this example by assuming more generally that $X_{\mathbb{Q}} \to B_{\mathbb{Q}}$ admits exactly $m$ sections defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and ask whether the density of $b \in B(\mathbb{Z})$ with $|X_b(\mathbb{Q})| > m$ is zero. Alternatively, drop the properness and generic smoothness assumptions, including instead the assumption that the smooth projective model of the generic fibre has genus $> 1$.

Comment: I guess the answer is trivially yes, because the hypotheses are never fulfilled. If $B(\mathbb{Z})$ contains an element $b$, then $X_b$ must be a proper smooth curve over $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ of genus $>1$, and such curves don't exist.

Comment: Edited: what I really wanted to say is that $X_{\mathbb{Q}} \to B_{\mathbb{Q}}$ was a smooth proper family of curves. So I have replaced "smooth" by "generically smooth."

Comment: What does "proportion" mean in this general context?

Comment: It means the following. Let $h$ be a height function on $B$ given by some projective embeding (assume, to fix ideas, that $B$ is quasi-projective). Then the proportion is the lim, or the lim sup, as $H \to \infty$ of the ratio $|b \in Z \mid h(b) \leq H| / |b \in B(\mathbb{Z}) \mid h(b) \leq H|$, where $Z \subset B(\mathbb{Z})$ is the set of $b$ for which $X_b$ does have a rational point.

Comment: That's expected but has not been proved. There has been some recent progress for the universal family of hyperelliptic curves by Bharghava, Gross, Poonen and Stoll.

Comment: It is better, in view of both comments, to say that $B$ is a quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{Q}$, rather than a finite-type scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$. I will edit to adjust this.

Comment: @ Felipe: Thanks! Let me ask you the question which came up in the above link. Given an appropriate number field $K$ (e.g. a polyquadratic field), would it indeed be true that the $K$-rank of a random elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ is strictly $> 1/2$?

Comment: "would it indeed be true that the K-rank of a random elliptic curve over ℚ is strictly >1/2?" Sorry, I don't know the answer to that and I don't see a reason for it to be true or false. I have somehow missed the earlier question. I'll have a look.

Comment: Although the meaning of this question has been clear from the start (and I haven't got a clue what the answer is), there are still issues with the precise formulation. If $B$ is a variety over $\mathbf{Q}$ then $B(\mathbf{Z})$ is empty.

Comment: Indeed... Sorry about this. I have edited again.

Comment: For "explicit variant" of your question you may consult the paper by Andrew Granville "Rational and integral points on quadratic twists of a given hyperelliptic curve" IMRN (2007), in particular Corollary 1 (ii) and Conjecture 1 (ii). 
I am wondering what is known (or conjectured) concering the same question for degree 4 (the mentioned paper deals with integer points for degree 4, but not with rational points). 